# Editing the content of a PostgreSQL table through the data output of a query

Tags: windows, osx, postgresql

I am looking for a Windows 7 or OS X program that can query a PostgreSQL table, and let me edit the table by editing the data output of a query. I know how to code it, but I am wondering whether there exists some GUIs that can take care of that. Any license and any price is fine.

pgAdmin III [does not allow](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/133469/9622) the user to edit the data output of a query.

Comment: Would a web-based tool like [phppgadmin](https://github.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin) be an option? I'm not using it, but its name suggests similarity to phpMyAdmin ;)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks, I prefer not web-based, but that'd be okay too.